# Is there any tools for check html quality?

Tags: html, standards

I know about html, css validation and some rules in pagespeed about css performance.
Is there any all in one tool for checking?
May be it can check some best practice for html markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For HTML, consider using [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It yells at me for not including `summary` attributes in my `<table>` tags. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Use this Html Validator 0.8.5.8 with firefox .

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249

It will show error and will give best suggestion

[image]

And this CodeBurner for Firefox 1.0 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13048

[image]

And if you need software, then use this http://www.freehtmlvalidator.com/

And if you need online tool, then go for this http://www.onlinewebcheck.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider YSlow firefox extension from yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

- [Web Page Analyzer](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/)
- Google [SpeedTracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/)
- Safari/Webkit Web Inspector

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [The W3C QA Toolbox](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) (for Markup, Links, CSS validation) and the popular [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) Firefox extension, [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) (another Firefox extension) and SpeedTracer (sort of like YSlow!, but for Google Chrome) which are more performance oriented.